# CS50 pset1 credit 'segmentation fault core dump' error

Tags: c, cs50, credit-card

I am getting a Segmentation fault core dump error when I run my credit question from CS50 pset1. I am new to coding . Any help would be nice.

In the function, I, checking whether the number provided is from any credit card companies. After that, it is checked for authenticity using Luhn's Algorithm which checks if the final sum has a zero in its unit's place

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

string card(long a);
int main(void)
{
    long credit_num;
    do
    {
        credit_num = get_long ("Enter Credit Card Number");
    }
    while (false);

    printf("%s", card(credit_num));
}


string card(long a)
{
    bool b = false;
    string c = (string) a;
    string name;

    // checking card type
    if ((c [0] == '3' && (c[1] == '4' || c [1] == '7')) && strlen(c) == 15 )
    {
        name = "AMEX\n ";
    }
    else if ((c [0] == '5' && (c [1] == '1'|| c [1] == '2' || c [1] == '3' || c[1] == '4' || c [1] == '5')) && strlen(c) == 16)
    {
        name = "MASTERCARD\n";
    }
    else if (c [0] == '4' && (strlen(c)== 13 || strlen(c)== 16))
    {
        name = "VISA\n";
    }
    else
    {
        name= "INVALID\n";
    }

    /// adding to check Luhn's Algorithm
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=-2; abs(i)<strlen(c); i=i-2)
    {
        int dbl= 2*(int)c[i];
        int r = dbl % 10;
        // sepearting digits for double digit answers
        if (r >0)
        {
            sum = sum + r + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + dbl;
        }
    }
    // adding the remaining digits to the sum

    for (int i=-1; abs(i)<=strlen(c); i=i-2)
    {
        sum= sum + (int)c[i];
    }

//// Checking if last digit is 0

    // printf(sum);
    if (sum%10==0)
    {
        return name;
    }
    else
    {
        return "INVALID";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `string c = (string) a;` does? Certainly doesn't convert the `long int` to a `string`.

Comment: `string c = (string) a;` is actually `char *c = (char*) a;`. Now it should be clear.

Comment: Use `sprintf` and an array of `char` to convert to string. The *type* `string` is actually masking a pointer to char `char *`.

Comment: Aside don't use integers for card, phone and other "numbers" which are actually digit strings, so input as a string to begin with.